# ReactiveAsyncCommand.RegisterAsyncAction - missing completion notification?

Tags: c#, .net, reactiveui

I'm using ReactiveUI. On a button, I want to call a webservice. If this call succeeds, I want to update my UI.

When registering an asynchronous function with `RegisterAsyncFunction`, you get an observable that you can subscribe to. This gives you the opportunity to run code when the async code returns, and you can also `ObserveOnDispatcher()` to run code on the UIThread.

The only problem is - my command have no return value.

I figure `RegisterAsyncAction` is for this purpose, but I can't find any way of knowing when this action is done.

What would be the right way of using a ReactiveAsyncCommnand in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hwhoops, it looks like you've found a bug in `RegisterAsyncAction`, it should return `IObservable<Unit>`

In the meantime, just copy-paste the corrected version into your app, it's just an Extension Method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// RegisterAsyncAction registers an asynchronous method that runs
    /// whenever the Command's Execute method is called and doesn't return a
    /// result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="calculationFunc">The function to be run in the
    /// background.</param>
    public static IObservable<Unit> RegisterAsyncAction(this IReactiveAsyncCommand This, 
        Action<object> calculationFunc,
        IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {
        return This.RegisterAsyncFunction(x => { calculationFunc(x); return Unit.Default; }, scheduler);
    }
```

> and you can also `ObserveOnDispatcher()` to run code on the UIThread.

You actually don't need to do this, RxUI already guarantees that the result of `Register*` will come back on the UI thread.

Comment: I switched to `RegisterAsyncFunction`, returning a dummy value. A little later, I found a `AsyncCompletedNotification` on ReactiveAsyncCommand. I didn't try it, but it looks like a possible solution?

Comment: It is, though it loses the data from the returned method - it's better to use the return result from Register*

Comment: And in this case, there is no return value to lose. But a `RegisterAsyncAction` that returns an `IObservable` is in any case better. Thanks!